# Macro expansion issue with gcc

Tags: gcc, macros

In gcc, it appears that referencing the results of a macro expansion later inside that same expansion doesn't work. For example:

```
#define TESTMACRO(name) \
        static int name##_func(int solNo) { \
                return (solNo); \
        }\
        static int name##Thing = {0,##name##_func},NULL,{"", capInvSw##name}}; 

TESTMACRO(stuff)
```

This results in errors like this:

```
test.c:7:29: error: pasting "," and "stuff" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  static int name##Thing = {0,##name##_func},NULL,{"", capInvSw##name`}}; 
                             ^
test.c:9:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TESTMACRO’
 TESTMACRO(stuff)
```

I would expect to have a function called stuff_func created and passed into stuffThing. I believe that this works in other compilers. What is the equivalent way to do this in gcc?

Comment: What does your pre-processor output present for the expansion?

Comment: Looks like you have a spurious extra ## in the macro body, which is what the error message is complaining about...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run only the pre-processor on your code by passing the `-E` flag:

```
gcc -E foo.c
```

Which evaluates your macro to:

```
static int stuff_func(int solNo) { return (solNo); } static int stuffThing = {0,stuff_func},NULL,{"", capInvSwstuff`}};
```

That can be expanded for readability to:

```
static int stuff_func(int solNo) { 
return (solNo); 
} 

static int stuffThing = {0,stuff_func},NULL,{"", capInvSwstuff`}};
```

And it appears that you have one extra/missing brackets `}` in your expanded macro.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, yes, this was an artificial example meant to strip some ambiguity from a real life pinmame issue.